# Nested *ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to dynamically create card having card header and card body. I have fixed size of an array that is being used to print in the card header. However, when it comes to card body I am having an issue. I have a fixed array but I want to print some values below 1st card-header, some below 2nd card header and so on. How can I achieve this? I have tried a lot but couldn't figure it out. What my program does is that it only prints one value below each card header and then prints the rest of the values without anything in the header.

Here's my code:

> HTML

```
<div class="card-header" id = "searchingcardheader">
    <p>{{fetchedData[0].CMPNYNAME}}</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf = "containsData">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div style = "width: 70%; margin: auto;" *ngFor = "let data of fetchedData; let i = index">
        <div class="card-header">
          <p>{{cardCheckArray[i]}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>{{data.DOCUMENT_NAME}}</p>
          <p>{{data.DATE_SUBMITTED | date: 'medium'}}</p>
          <p>{{data.PROCESS_NAME}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am removing the repeated values for the process name in my typescript. I want 1 Process Name in the card header and then 2-3 the values in the card body for each header.

> TypeScript

```
var swap = this.fetchedData[0].PROCESS_NAME;

      for (var x in this.fetchedData)
      {
        if(swap == this.fetchedData[x].PROCESS_NAME)
        {
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
          this.cardCheckArray.push(swap);
          swap = this.fetchedData[x].PROCESS_NAME;
        }
      }
this.cardCheckArray.push(swap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a static index or that was just to exemplify?
I mean in this line:

```
<p>{{fetchedData[0].CMPNYNAME}}</p>
```

This is an example using nested ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemsArray; let i = index">
     <p>{{fetchedData[index].CMPNYNAME}}</p>
     <div *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems; let j = index">
          <p>{{subItem[j]}}</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some approaches using Angular Material Card with a static `array` as `data` and `*ngFor`

TS file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Card with multiple sections
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'card-fancy-example',
  templateUrl: 'card-fancy-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['card-fancy-example.css'],
})
export class CardFancyExample {
 data: Array<Data> =[
    { id: 1_000, name: "First", infoHead: `Title `, infoBody: `Body`, state: true},
    { id: 2_000, name: "First", infoHead: `Title `, infoBody: `Body `, state: false},
    { id: 3_000, name: "First", infoHead: `Title `, infoBody: `Body `, state: true}
   ]
 
 }

interface Data {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  infoHead: string
  infoBody: string,
  state: boolean
}
```

HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let card of data">
  <mat-card class="example-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
      <mat-card-title>Name: {{ card.name + card.id }}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>title: {{ card.infoHead + card.id }}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>
        Name: {{ card.infoBody + card.id }}
      </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
      <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
  <br>
</div>
```

You can visit the demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzrjoy?file=src/app/card-fancy-example.html)